# Diff 2 data series values using jq

Tags: json, object, jq, difference

I'm not an expert jq user and I have tried a lot of different solutions now on how to solve my problem.
I have a number of series of data that belongs to a specific version that I want to calculate the difference between. The base data will always be an array with two elements containing the data serie's values. The number of values within each series can vary, i.e. the number of "valX" values is not constant.
The result should give all values "ver1"-"ver2".

The resulting data given below is an example of how I would like the end result. If the values are missing trailing "0", i.e. 1.20 => 1.2 and leading zero is missing, i.e. 0.01 => .01, that is no problem.

Example JSON source data:

```
[
  {
    "version": "ver1",
    "series": [
      {
        "id": "name1",
        "val1": "0.77",
        "val2": "1.34",
        "val3": "7.89",
        "val4": "6.00"
      },
      {
        "id": "name2",
        "val1": "0.34",
        "val2": "1.00",
        "val3": "12.15"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "version": "ver2",
    "series": [
      {
        "id": "name1",
        "val1": "0.35",
        "val2": "2.34",
        "val3": "6.50",
        "val4": "6.01"
      },
      {
        "id": "name2",
        "val1": "2.54",
        "val2": "0.55",
        "val3": "13.20"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And I want a result like this or fairly similar:

```
[
  {
    "id": "name1",
    "val1": "-0.42",
    "val2": "1.00",
    "val3": "-1.39",
    "val4": "0.01"
  },
  {
    "id": "name2",
    "val1": "-2.20",
    "val2": "-0.45",
    "val3": "1.05"
  }
]
```

Anyone with the knowledge that can help me or at least bump me in the correct direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, please fix the JSON in your example.

Second, rest assured jq is well-suited for this task, but it will
require some understanding of jq to devise a complete solution
to the problem.

Since the problem statement
is currently somewhat underspecified, and since SO is not
a free programming service, I'll focus here on the
key functionality required, which I take to be finding
the "difference" between two objects with the same `id`
and whose other keys are numerical strings.

#### Data suitable for testing

Let's start with the two objects:

```
def s1: {
  "id": "name1",
  "val1": "0.77",
  "val2": "1.34",
  "val3": "7.89",
  "val4": "6.00"
  };

def s2: {
  "id": "name1",
  "val1": "0.35",
  "val2": "2.34",
  "val3": "6.50",
  "val4": "6.01"
  };
```

#### minus/2

The hard part here is actually the numerical rounding, which is taken care of by the inner function `round(n)`:

```
# $a - $b
def minus($a; $b):
  def round(n):
    (if . < 0 then -1 else 1 end) as $s
    | $s*10*.*n
    | if (floor % 10) > 4 then (.+5) else . end
    | ./10 | floor/n | .*$s;

  def m($k): ($a[$k]|tonumber) - ($b[$k]|tonumber) | round(100);
  reduce ($a|keys_unsorted[]) as $k ({};
    if $k == "id" then .id = $a["id"]
    else .[$k] = m($k)
    end);

  minus(s2; s1)
```

(If you really want the difference between two numbers
to be a string, simply add a call to `tostring`.)

#### Output

```
{
  "id": "name1",
  "val1": -0.42,
  "val2": 1,
  "val3": -1.39,
  "val4": 0.01
}
```

#### Hint

The following invocation of `minus/2` produces the result shown below when given the sample data provided (after it has been corrected):

```
map(.series) | transpose | map(minus(.[1]; .[0]))
```

The result:

```
[
  {
    "id": "name1",
    "val1": -0.42,
    "val2": 1,
    "val3": -1.39,
    "val4": 0.01
  },
  {
    "id": "name2",
    "val1": 2.2,
    "val2": -0.45,
    "val3": 1.05
  }
]
```

#### The rest

... is up to you.  It will depend on how careful you want to be about
matching the "id" values, handling edge cases, and so on.

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate answer. I think this will help me just fine.
Sorry for the invalid JSON (now fixed), I of course had to add one extra data row in the "name1" series just before posting :-/. Had validated the JSON prior to that.